# Reference for continuous (multivariate) distributions?

Tags: distributions, references, multivariate-distribution

A reference that not just enlist the formulas of continuous (multivariate) distributions but goes in details about them and maybe treat the relations between them (e.g. derivation/proofs, intuition and applications).

Of course the normal distribution is not the problem, but, for example, the following are hardly touched in many books:

- Gamma, Beta
- Chi-square
- Student's t
- Multivariate Student's t

> I found these references/books so far:
>
> - **[statlect.com](https://www.statlect.com/)**: contains all the mentioned distributions above but still feels like just a
>   database of formulas.
> - **Introduction to Probability, Second Edition By Joseph K. Blitzstein, Jessica Hwang :** this book touches on non-multivariate
>   continuous distribution, and a good gamma, beta reference.

Comment: Because most of the distribution names you have listed apply only to *univariate* distributions, could you please be more specific about what you mean by "multivariate"?

Comment: @whuber Any distribution over random vectors (if it exists). Of course there are more continuous distributions. But, those felt related (including the normal distribution), thus I guess maybe there's a reference that treat them as such.

Comment: The series of volumes by Johnson, Kotz, and Balakrishnan is extremely thorough. (See this [Google image search](https://www.google.com/search?hs=Bfx&channel=fs&q=johnson+kotz) as an illustration ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reference that goes into much detail about some of this distribution, like the Wishart distribution, which is a matrix analogy of the chi-square distributions. So it appears in theory of manova. That is Robb Muirhead's [Aspects of Multivariate Statistical Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471769851).

Another good book going even more into the mathemathical theory behind the calculations is R. H. Farrell's [Techniques of Multivariate Calculation (Lecture Notes in Mathematics)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540076956) .   If you want something more basic, you can say so in a comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't try to read them yet, but if you could enlist more basic resources for me and future viewers, it would be nice.